# Check for javascript file in view helper?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a view helper that needs jquery, jqueryui, knockout and few other js files to work. Some pages already references all the js files needed by view helper, some pages don't.

Right now, I am using the url to figure out if a js file should be referenced or not inside the view helper.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question in the right way, but I'm 100% sure you need to manage your javascript dependencies in a better way.

I usually use [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) module loader to manage javascript files included into a template.

In order to use it, you need to download [require.js file](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html) and place it somewhere in your project. I believe you would like to place it in `./public/js/vendors` directory not to keep it alongside with your own code. Also, you need to create `config` file for it, where you decide what javascript modules are needed.

So, the concept is pretty clear: if you have javascript files, that are related to some part of your project, for example `admin panel`, you should create a `config` that will load those files. I usually have one config for `admin panel` part of my web application, and another one for `user side` of it.

This config with require.js itself are included into template like this:

```
<script data-main="./js/config-admin.js" src="./js/vendor/require.js"></script>
```

You need to keep in mind, that on every template you should have only one inclusion of javascript - the inclusion of require.js and it's config.

The config usually looks like this:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: '/public/js',
  paths: {
    'bootstrap': './vendor/bootstrap',
    'jquery': './vendor/jquery'
  },
  shim: {
    'bootstrap': ['jquery']
  }                                                                                                                   
});

require(['./app'], function (app) {
    console.log(app); //Here is smth that required module 'public/js/app.js' returns
    //Do some coding here if you wish, for example to start js application.
});
```

If you need more examples of usage, you can visit my github profile, there are a couple of repositories where I use it (symfony and zend2 applications).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not managing your assets via other means, the [`HeadScript`](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.head-script.html#headscript-helper) view helper is designed to act as a collection of the scripts that should be rendered in the view.

Considering the helper *depends* on the JS files, placing these in the helper's factory class would be a logical place.

```
class MyViewHelperFactory
{
    public function __invoke(ViewPluginManager $viewHelperManager, $name, $requestedName)
    {
        $headScriptHelper = $viewHelperManager->get('HeadScript');
        $headScriptHelper->appendFile('/js/file.js');

        return new MyViewHelper();
    }
}
```

There are of course better ways of doing these things; personally I like [Assetic](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic).